# The Babel Brotherhood - #3 (Fan Made)

Tags: language

Recently, the puzzles of @Racso and @PerpetualJ caught my attention and I had to make one myself. Check out [The Babel Brotherhood - #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72886/the-babel-brotherhood-1) and [The Babel Brotherhood - #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72889/the-babel-brotherhood-2) if you're unsure how this works.

---

Two members of the Babel Brotherhood, Cologne and Meatball were involved in a fight. Cologne gets badly injured and falls to the floor.

"Cologne!" Meatball exclaims. "Are you alright? Is there severe pain anywhere?" Cologne replies, but Meatball simply gives a sigh of relief and puts aside medical attention for later.

What did Cologne say to make Meatball think the injury was fine?

Hint 1:

> Maybe Cologne wasn't the best codename, something closer to Boutique would make more sense.

Comment: I'm fine, and I feel alright? :P

Comment: Ohhhh this one is harder because I don’t speak either language! Lol perhaps meatball is Italian? Hrmmm..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Cologne says...

> arm or in French bras

This would be interpreted by Meatball as...

> Bra in Swedish or 'fine' in english

Language origins...

> Cologne is from Cologne, Germany hence his nickname but he speaks Colognian or Kölsch which is a German French hybrid with many similarities to French?  Meatball I am guessing is Swedish due to his love and pride of Swedish Meatballs.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe he said

> schnell

Which means

> "quickly" in Cologne's language, German.

But sounds like

> snäll

which means

> "nice" in Meatball's language, Swedish.

Comment: +1 for the effort, but the interaction is more clear than that.

Answer (score 2):

> Cologne speaks German and said "Bein" because his leg was hurt, but it sounded like "fine" in Meatball's English.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the hint that

> Cologne might be better named Boutique, I conclude that the Frenchman got bopped on the nose.

Cologne is

> French, so when he was asked if anything hurt he indicated it was his *nez* (pronounced /*ne*/).

Meatball is

> Swedish, so when he heard Boutique say *nez* he interpreted it as *nej* (pronounced /*nɛj*/), which is Swedish for no.

Comment: Don't think there's a diphtong in the pronunciation of the first one. That said, it might still sound a bit like the second word for a native speaker.

Comment: @jafe I’ve always pronounced it -ay at the end, but I’ve also heard it with -eh as well. That’s the first thing that came to mind, anyway!

Comment: You got the basic idea, I'm sure you'll get the one I'm thinking of very soon.

Comment: @Zimonze is either word correct? I’m not sure which one you mean.

Comment: No, but the languages are correct and you are almost there. Just remember what Meatball asked, "no" would not cause him to do what he did.

Comment: “No” would certainly do so for “Is there severe pain anywhere?” I feel....

Answer (score 0):

Cologne said-

> Bein in his german, cause his leg was hurt (Thanks to @Rasco)

MeatBall thought-

> Bene, which in italian means fine, meatball is obviously italian, i mean come on pasta and meatballs anyone? :P

Comment: When pronounced, "bein" in German doesn't sound as "bene" at all. That's why I picked English as a more probable answer.